# vars() dictionary in python between successive script runs

Tags: python, dictionary, namespaces

I am trying to develop a simpler protocol for documenting the namespace of my work environment, before, during and after a script is run.  Apparently, the only things I have available in Python, is to access the vars(), locals() or globals() dictionaries before I run a script, then immediately after.  This is moderately successful, in the sense that I can capture the namespace additions (via their keys) but I have no way of knowing the order in which the various entities are added to the dictionary.  Short of manually sorting the list to produce a time sequential list, is there anything I have overlooked in trying to determine the order that the namespace is created.  Below is the results of a before and after snapshot of the vars() dictionary:

```
>>> # vars() keys before running script
>>> vars_keys_0 = vars().keys()
>>> for key in vars_keys_0:
...     print('key: {:<15} - {}'.format(key,type(vars()[key])))
... 
key: __builtins__    - <type 'module'>
key: __name__        - <type 'str'>
key: pywin           - <type 'module'>
key: __doc__         - <type 'NoneType'>
key: __package__     - <type 'NoneType'>
>>> 
>>> # vars() keys after running script
>>> vars_keys_1 = vars().keys()
>>> for key in vars_keys_1:
...     print('key: {:<15} - {}'.format(key,type(vars()[key])))
...     
key: rand_pnts       - <class 'numpy.core.records.recarray'>
key: arr             - <class 'numpy.core.records.recarray'>
key: random          - <type 'module'>
key: extent_LRBT     - <type 'function'>
key: pnts            - <type 'list'>
    ..... snip ....
key: lineIntersect   - <type 'function'>
key: from_XsYs       - <type 'function'>
key: from_extent     - <type 'function'>
key: Xs              - <type 'list'>
key: vars_keys_0     - <type 'list'>
key: lineIntersect2  - <type 'function'>
>>>
```

Differences between steps are easy to collect via sets:

```
v1 = vars().keys() # at step 1
v2 = vars().keys() # at step 2 then
diff = set(v2).difference(set(v1))  # yields the difference in namespace
```

The dictionaries are unordered as expected, but surely I am missing something that would enable one to gather namespace additions in sequential order.

EDIT:
With the additional suggestion from below, I tried this simple script to test

```
import sys
def zipper(Xs,Ys):
  '''zip two lists'''
  return zip(Xs,Ys)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
  _order = []
  _seen = set(vars())
  def trace_names(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call' and arg is None:
      # enter first frame, return 'local' trace
      return trace_names
    if event in ('line', 'return'):
      # (last) line in top-level frame executed
      _order.extend(frame.f_globals.viewkeys() - _seen)
      _seen.update(frame.f_globals)
  sys.settrace(trace_names)

  Xs = [0,0,2,2,0]
  Ys = [1,3,3,1,1]
  print('Zipped lists {}',format(zipper(Xs,Ys)))

  sys.settrace(None)
  print(_order)
```

The results unfortunately are more confusing:
('Zipped lists {}', '[(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (0, 1)]')
['trace_names', '_seen', 'Xs', 'Ys', 'CmdTarget', 'Object', 'win32ui', 'default_scintilla_encoding', 'app', 'Queue', 'thread_test', 'WindowOutputDocument', 'WindowOutputDocumentParent', 're', 'window', 'WindowOutputViewScintilla', 'test', 'string', 'WindowOutput', 'scintillacon', 'docview', 'WindowOutputView', 'RTFWindowOutput', 'WindowOutputFrame',.......'ScintillaControlInterface', 'EM_GETSELTEXT', 'EM_EXSETSEL', 'dllid', 'EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR', 'EM_FINDTEXTEX', 'ScintillaNotification', 'os']

If the def placement is in error, please advise.

Comment: I don't understand why the order matters here.

Comment: Simple...I am trying to develop a flowchart of the process run.  I use flowcharts for teaching purposes and also for documention, ergo, order is important.  I manually order the differences in the dictionaries now.  My question then becomes, python "knows" when things were done...is there a way to access this list of events from namespace or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to track order is to use full-on tracing. You could do that with the [`sys.settrace()` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace), but you'll have to move everything into a `main()` function as you cannot attach a tracer to the *current* frame, only new frames:

```
import sys

_order = []
_seen = set()

def trace_names(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call' and arg is None:
        # enter first frame, return 'local' trace
        return trace_names
    if event in ('line', 'return'):
        # (last) line in top-level frame executed
        _order.extend(frame.f_locals.viewkeys() - _seen)
        _seen.update(frame.f_locals)

sys.settrace(trace_names)

# run your script
main()

sys.settrace(None)
print(_order)
```

This traces the order of locals added in the next scope *only*; if any functions modify globals you could not determine their exact order other than in whole groups, by inspecting `globals()` from the tracer.

Comment: That I am afraid yielded everything...
['pnts', 'Ys', 'trace_names', '_seen', 'Xs', 'fromarrays', 'array', '__all__', 'record', '_typestr', 'types', 'fromfile', 'nt', '_byteorderconv', 'chararray', 'ndarray', 'isfileobj', 'get_remaining_size', 'format_parser', 'bytes', 'find_duplicate', 'recarray', 'fromstring', 'sb', 'os', 'fromrecords', 'numfmt', 'arr', 'CmdTarget', 'Object', 'win32ui', 'default_scintilla_encoding', 'app', ...... plus hundreds more.  I loaded the above after my if __name__ == "__main__": line with the last two lines after the __main__ code block

Comment: @Dan: put your main code in a function, and if needed trace the `f_locals` too. You are now tracing the globals of anything your top-level code calls.

Comment: tried in a main block and I got rid of it and moved everything after the defs with my code between your ... sys.settrace(trace_names) ... my 4 lines of code ... sys.settrace(None) and I got the following with or without a main block >>> ('Zipped lists {}', '[(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (0, 1)]')
['Xs', 'Ys', 'self', 'attr', 'o', 'msg', 'message', 'item', 'timeout', 'block', 'n', '_Condition__waiters', .... 'rc', 'len', 'str', 'end', 'currentPos', 'anchorPos', 'atEnd', 'text', 'start', 'cr', 'crBuff', 'addressCrBuff'] .  I think I am getting further from what I need

Comment: @DanPatterson: made it a little clearer; you *have* to start a new scope, at which point you may as well use a `main` function (or you'd need to make this a separate file and import your original script as a module, at which point you'll need to trace `f_globals`).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Martijn but at this stage I think it will be quicker to collect namespace in my doc header as I go along.